# Can I change python multiprocess entry point?

Tags: python, multiprocess

## **Python multiprocess entry point could be controlled?**

I've injected `run_entry` function on `entry.py`.

But why new process importing `main.py` again?

instead of starting with run_entry func on entry.py by direct importing entry.py

I've tested it on Windows 10 (Python 3.9.13).

I want to use inter-process communication by shared memory Queue.

So, I don't want to use a subprocess.

but Is there any method to use Queue with subprocess?

main.py

```
from entry import call_multi_process

print(f'i am IMPORTED MAIN : {__name__} <-- WHY THIS LOADED MULTIPLE TIMES?')


def main():
    call_multi_process()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('i am the GENESIS OF MAIN')
    main()
    print('i am the ENDGAME OF MAIN')
```

entry.py

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

import psutil

print(f'i am IMPORTED AS MULTIPROCESS ENTRY OWNER : {__name__}')


def run_entry(num: int):
    name = psutil.Process().name()

    print(f'I AM MULTIPROCESS BODY / {__name__} / {num}:{name} {psutil.Process().pid}')
    time.sleep(1)


def call_multi_process():
    # I WANT PURE NEWLY CREATED PROCESS ONLY WITH IMPORTING THIS PY FILE WITHOUT MAIN
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(initargs=('name', 'test')) as pool:
        for i in range(3):
            pool.submit(run_entry, i)
            # time.sleep(1)
```

## Output

i am IMPORTED AS MULTIPROCESS ENTRY OWNER : pyutil.tests.new_process_entry

i am IMPORTED MAIN : _*main*_ <-- WHY THIS LOADED MULTIPLE TIMES?

i am the GENESIS OF MAIN

i am IMPORTED AS MULTIPROCESS ENTRY OWNER : pyutil.tests.new_process_entry

**i am IMPORTED MAIN : _*mp_main*_ <-- WHY THIS LOADED MULTIPLE TIMES?**

I AM MULTIPROCESS BODY / pyutil.tests.new_process_entry / 0:python.exe 30596

i am IMPORTED AS MULTIPROCESS ENTRY OWNER : pyutil.tests.new_process_entry

**i am IMPORTED MAIN : _*mp_main*_ <-- WHY THIS LOADED MULTIPLE TIMES?**

I AM MULTIPROCESS BODY / pyutil.tests.new_process_entry / 1:python.exe 28200

i am IMPORTED AS MULTIPROCESS ENTRY OWNER : pyutil.tests.new_process_entry

**i am IMPORTED MAIN : _*mp_main*_ <-- WHY THIS LOADED MULTIPLE TIMES?**

I AM MULTIPROCESS BODY / pyutil.tests.new_process_entry / 2:python.exe 6336

i am the ENDGAME OF MAIN